# How do I map my domain URL the root folder of my Grails app?

Tags: tomcat, grails, amazon-ec2, url-mapping

I have a Grails app called abc, which when I access locally I get at through

```
http://localhost:port/abc
```

I have deployed my app up on Amazon EC2 with an elastic IP address which I can get at directly as

```
http://1.2.3.4/abc
```

I have a domain name of xyz.com and I have pointed that at my elastic IP, so now I can go to

```
http://xyz.com
http://www.xyz.com
```

The problem is that xyz.com points at the root folder for the tomcat server.  What I want it to do is map the .com domains to `http://1.2.3.4/abc` so that my home page shows instead of the tomcat welcome screen.

What's the best way to do this?  Should I reconfigure the domain name mapping somehow or should I change the tomcat settings somehow or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you rename the war file to ROOT.war (case sensitive) then when you deploy it to Tomcat it will be the root context at http://1.2.3.4/ and http://www.xyz.com will work.

If you also want to run your local app with the root context add this line to application.properties

```
app.context=/
```

and then 'grails run-app' will run at http://localhost:8080/

Comment: Thanks.  Does adding the property not work for all deployments?  I am inferring from what you have written that it only works for localhost.  I am deploying through CloudFoundry and I'm not sure that I can change the name of the war file it deploys, I'll investigate.

Comment: The property is only for run-app.

Answer (score 1):

You can create [Virtual Hosts in Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html).  The do a pretty good job of explaining it on the linked page so I won't try to paraphrase here.